# Generating Unsigned APK with Android Studio 0.8.9

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I want to generate **unsigned** APK for my app in Android studio but I don't know how to do it in Android Studio 0.8.9

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio use

```
Run -> Run 'YourProject'
```

to build the code and create the unsigned apk. You can find your apk file under

```
$YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/outputs/apk
```